# libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found

Tags: opengl, electron, x11, xvfb

I get error when running `xvfb-run electron app/`

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

The electron app is just opening a simple html file.
Ubuntu 16.04

I've found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-driver-for-a-geforce-gt-630/451248#451248) post but the solution is about nvidia drivers which is not my case.

Comment: Can you describe your setup? What graphic card do you use? Which graphic drivers are in use?

Comment: Now I'm using CentOS 7.3 on server. Here is what I've installed for electron to work with XVFB. 
xorg-x11-server-Xvfb gtk2 libXtst libXScrnSaver GConf2 dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts gcc
Except printing these errors in console, everything works normal so I ignore that LibGL error.